# Prevent Changes from being merged to develop

Tags: git, git-flow

I have a common question regarding Git-Flow.

For normal the finishing of a release says, that all changes from the release should be merged to develop and master.

What If there are changes that are not allowed to be merged to develop? E.g. one-time hotfix scripts that have been introduced last minute within the release-branch?

Is release-branching the wrong place for such files? Should they be extracted to a specific hotfix-branch which then will NOT be finished using git-flow?

I know a lot of you will say "don't introduce throw away code" but it is necessary sometimes (to prevent e.g. a too complex code-logic)

Comment: I was pointed to an interesting blog post about the theme: http://endoflineblog.com/gitflow-considered-harmful

Comment: Can you give an example of a bug fix which should be made, but only temporarily?  I can't even think of your scenario happening in real life.

Comment: E.g. Database Changes which should only be called once for a specific release. Or Code changes which have accidentally be performed (or added by branching) within the release branch and will be deleted there but are needed in develop.

Comment: Well, you could do a cleanup on the release branch before merging to back to `develop` or `master`.  You could remove the hot fix commits and other stuff you don't want.  Not ideal, but it should work.